# What methods are in Jenkins jobs.scripts.WorkflowScript

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a multibranch Pipeline Project in Jenkins.
I use my Jenkinsfile as a Seed Job which creates Jobs and scripts to be executed.

One of these jobs needs to run on a slave and I need to do file operations for this job on the slave. The File operations are implemented using the FilePath class. All I need right now is the channel to construct my FilePath.

How do I get the channel from within the WorkflowScript? Where can I find an API Reference for the  WorkflowScript.

What I already found out is that I get all instance Channels by this code

```
 println Jenkins.instance.slaves
 for(def slave : Jenkins.instance.slaves){
     println slave.channel        
 }
```

But How do I find out in which instance is my script running?

Any Suggestions? Pointers to the API or some Workaround for my Problem.

Thank You

Comment: Why do you want to do this in a `Jenkinsfile`? What are you trying to accomplish overall? Why can't you use the existing `node` step and `sh` functionality? To me, this question sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: What I'm actually trying to accomplish is to start a customized configured (Apache) webserver on an Jenkins client. For this I need to change https.conf file before starting the webserver. I' prefer using groovy classes over sh/bat command, because I'm more familiar with groovy and I know better to test groovy classes then actually sh/bat commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the (crappy) Solution I came up with.

I wrote myself a Util class to get the channel for the label I used for the job.

```
import jenkins.model.Jenkins
import hudson.FilePath
import hudson.remoting.Channel    
/**
 * returns the channel of the given label, might be null 
 * 
 * realy bad solution why: when multiple JenkinsSlaves have the same label, this will probably not work anymore, 
 * because the channel of the first node is returned
 * For empty labels it does not work either
 * @param jenkins the jenkins instance
 * @param label the associated label for the running node, not empty, not null
 * @return a channel of a Node associated with given label, might be null 
 */
@com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.NonCPS
public static Channel getChannel(Jenkins jenkins, String label) {
    assert jenkins !=null : 'JenkinsUtil.getChannel() does not work for null Jenkins'
    assert label!=null : 'JenkinsUtil.getChannel() does not work for null Labels'
    assert !label.isEmpty() : 'JenkinsUtil.getChannel() does not work for empty Labels' 
    Set<Node> nodes = jenkins.getLabel(label).getNodes()
    assert nodes.size() < 2 : 'JenkinsUtil.getChannel() might not work correctly for Label which are associated with multiple nodes. Fix Me!'
    assert nodes.size() > 0 : "JenkinsUtil.getChannel(): No node found for Label ${label}"
    return nodes[0].getChannel()
}
```

With this Channel I can now create the file on the remote machine.

```
FilePath remoteWorkspace = new FilePath(JenkinsUtil.getChannel(Jenkins.instance,LABEL_STRING), env.WORKSPACE)
FilePath webserverConfiguration = new FilePath( remoteWorkspace, 'webserver.conf')
webserverConfiguration.write('someText', null)
```

Why did I do it this way: 'build' variable was not available in the WorkkflowScript.